# Python web scraping of dynamic web page

Tags: python, json, dynamic, xmlhttprequest, html

guys
I'm sorry I just can't find some legit and working example how to pull xhr, json data from dynamic page. Thing is I had to login first and i succeded that but now i have to pull data that page is loading constantly. This is my code for now

```
import json, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib
from lxml import html
def collect():
   url = url
   cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
   br = mechanize.Browser()
   br.set_cookiejar(cj)
   br.set_handle_robots(False)
   br.open(url)

   br.select_form(nr=0)
   br.form['username'] = 'username'
   br.form['password'] = 'pass'
   br.submit()
   print br.response().read()
```

`

Comment: I would suggest using selenium for these type of task.

Comment: selenium is not my best option because I have to retrieve file, read it and save its values to database, this would have to function on my server when I'm done